# Does Swift support array vectorization and operations similar to numpy?

Tags: python, swift, numpy, vectorization

Does Swift natively support vectorization operations for its arrays? For example, in numpy, one can compute the matrix-vector product as such:

```
A = np.array([[1,2,1],
              [2,4,2],
              [1,2,1]])
B = np.array([1,2,4])
C = A.dot(B)
```

Where `C` is `[9 18 9]`. There are many other vectorized operations that numpy supports for its arrays.

Is there potentially something similar in Swift, e.g.

```
let A:[[Int]] = [[1,2,1],
                 [2,4,2],
                 [1,2,1]]
let B:[Int] = [1,2,4]
let C:[Int] = A.dot(B) /* <- Some form of vectorization operation? */
```

Comment: On Apple platforms there is the Accelerate framework, and there are Swift wrappers, for example https://github.com/mattt/Surge.

Comment: You can check GLKit it has methods to deal with matrices and vectors